# Use Before Declaration with Classes

Tags: c++

I'm having this issue with code evaluation. I want to use a function in one class, and use a function in another but I can't seem to get a prototype working for the function in the class.

```
class Pride
{
public:
    std::string firstMinion = "Pride";
    int prideAttackPlayer()
    {
        int damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) * attack;
        return damage;
    }
    int damagePride()
    {
        health = health - play.attackEnemy();
    }
    int outputHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }
private:
    int health = 20;
    int attack = 0;
    int defence = 0;
    int money = 0;
}pride;
class Player
{
public:
    int attackEnemy()
    {
        int damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) * attack;
        return damage;
    }
    void userAttack()
    {
        getline(std::cin, userInput);
        if (userInput == "1")
        {
            std::cout << pride.damagePride();
        }
    }
private:
    int health = 100;
    int attack = 0;
    int defence = 0;
    std::string userInput = "";
}play;
```

I want to use play.attackEnemy in the Pride class but it won't work due to evaluation errors. I think the fix is to use a prototype but I've tried with `int Player::attackEnemy() {};` and `class Player` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Code of a class is not aware of objects. `play` is an object. It gets defined later. Split your class declarations from your object instanciations. That will make the compiler messages more helpful for you.

Comment: Consider adding a parameter to `damagePride()`, which provides an attacking player. Then from that parameter you can call the `attackEnemy()`. E.g. `int prideAttackPlayer(Player play)`. Add a forward declaration of class Player and move the implementation to after the actual declaration of that class.

Comment: To put it differently, instantiate all objects in main, not before. Everything else should follow automatically if you work on the compiler messages you get then.

Comment: @Yunnosch So therefore, I am not allowed to use objects in my class functions?

Comment: More or less yes, there might be exceptions, but you should not bother about them now.

Comment: @Yunnosch I want to use the private members and combine the functions ffs, I must not use private members in order to do this? because what I want to do is use the attack private member variable of class and multiply it to the damage of the attack functions